# Why does my kNN model achieve perfect performance on my test set?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, model-evaluation

I have trained a KNN model using cross validation to minimize a custom loss function.  The model clearly overfits the training data, achieving a loss of zero but exhibits variation in 10-fold cross validation, achieving an average loss of -2,501,029.403.  Here are what the learning curves looks like:

[image: KNN Learning Curve]

With the observed variation in CV results, I would have expected the loss on the test set to be at least non-zero but it is not - it's zero.

To create the train (~5K examples) and test splits (~1K examples) I used stratified sampling on the target.  I have verified that data leakage is not at play here so I am left wondering why the classifier achieves perfect performance on the held-out test set.

I understand that that the model is suffering from high variance and is overfitting on the training set but why does this persist in the test set when the model has never seen that data?

**Update (Solved)**

To take a step back - I have abstracted a model and operations on it into a class.  To score the model, it looks like I was using a `score` function on this class which was written incorrectly:

```
def score(self, X, y, scorer):
    model_predictions = self.get_model_pipeline().fit(X, y).predict(X)
    X_transformed = self.pipeline.fit_transform(X)
    score = scorer(self.model, X_transformed, y)
    return (score, model_predictions)
```

You can see that the model is fit with `X` and then the score is calculated using the same `X`.  So this was a coding error on my part.

Comment: This question is not answerable without a reproducible example. Can you please post some code at least? Otherwise, are you sure there isn't some auto-normalization happening during training but not during testing time?

Comment: Thanks for your response - it got me looking more closely at some other code.  Normalization wasn't an issue but I did find the bad code in my search.  I was using a score function that was part of a class I wrote and that function fit the model and scored it using the same set.